# How do I display a grid in React using CSS grid

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-grid

I have a 2d array representing the columns (as opposed to rows):

```js
const cols = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3]
];
```

I am writing a React component to display a grid with this column data where each cell is a `20px x 20px` square with margins.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="board">
        {cols.map((col) => (
          <div className="column">
            {col.map((cell) => (
              <div className="cell">{cell}</div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.cell {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 0fr);
  gap: 20px;
}
```

but now only the columns are separated by the gap, rows are still not separated.

Here is [a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-wind-8wzdo6?file=/src/App.js).

I don't want to add margins to `cell` class directly as that will cause margins to the cells on the borders which is not what I want. I only want margins between them.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following properties to your `column` class:

```
.column {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```js
const cols = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3]
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="board">
        {cols.map((col, colIdx) => (
          <div className="column" key={colIdx}>
            {col.map((cell, cellIdx) => (
              <div className="cell" key={cellIdx}>{cell}</div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.cell {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 0fr);
  gap: 20px;
}

.column {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```